# Getting error net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED while axios get/post request in my react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kubernetes, axios

I am getting error

> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

in browser when my react app hit GET/POST request using axios. Do I need to do any additional things with axios request?

Url is able to access within pods (Kubernetes) but while accessing outside through app it is giving error

Comment: No, the website you are trying to access cannot be found probably by the DNS server, and thus that error.

Comment: @kiner_shah Thank you for the response, what could be the solution for this problem?

Comment: If you own the website you are trying to access, check why is it down? Else, you need to check if that website is up, trying ping to that website.

Comment: @kiner_shah, The url is it self giving response from there own pods but while trying to access from app it is giving such error even not accessible from postman.

Comment: Pods? Related to Kubernetes?

Comment: @kiner_shah Yes it is

Comment: ***The url is it self giving response from there own pods*** how do you check this? Also, please update the post to include these additional details.

Comment: I have checked by hitting url in pods, bcoz I own the website/url.

Comment: If your app or Postman can't access it, it must be probably because those pods are not visible to them. I am not a Kubernetes guy, but one query: Are your pods accessible to outside world (some nameserver configuration stuff)?

Comment: @kiner_shah It might be have some restriction, I need to check on that. I really appreciate your efforts and valuable discussion. 
I will update soon further workaround/solution to help others

Comment: How is the api service exposed in kubernetes ?

Comment: @TarunKhosla, API is not exposed out side(not accessible in postman too) and requirement is to access api only through some web server.

Comment: @LaxmikantW. , How is the API deployed ? Is it an external API service or your own service. Also what is the url that you are using to access the API.

Comment: @TarunKhosla Its our own service and which is accessible only within a pod and at the same place there is pod for frontend.

Comment: @TarunKhosla above error is gone by setting proxy in package.json of the base url of API but having issue with proxy (Proxy error: Could not proxy request /apiname from localhost:3000 to http://backendAPI (ECONNREFUSED).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share the solution here,

If the APIs are not exposed to outside world and only want to access through web app
simple set the base url with proxy in package.json like as below

```
"proxy":"https://yourbackendapi";
```

And deploy the application in the same environment where backend is deployed.

it will also resolved CORS related issue if any.